# How to log scrapy log into the Logstash

Tags: python, scrapy, logstash, elastic-stack

I've set up ELK stack on my server correctly and with using *python-logstash*  I could send my logs to logstash with the following snippet and everything is working correctly.

```
import logging
import logstash
import sys

host = 'localhost'

test_logger = logging.getLogger('python-logstash-logger')
test_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# test_logger.addHandler(logstash.LogstashHandler(host, 5959, version=1))
test_logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(host, 5000, version=1))

test_logger.error('python-logstash: test logstash error message.')
test_logger.info('python-logstash: test logstash info message.')
test_logger.warning('python-logstash: test logstash warning message.')

# add extra field to logstash message
extra = {
    'test_string': 'python version: ' + repr(sys.version_info),
    'test_boolean': True,
    'test_dict': {'a': 1, 'b': 'c'},
    'test_float': 1.23,
    'test_integer': 123,
    'test_list': [1, 2, '3'],
}
test_logger.info('python-logstash: test extra fields', extra=extra)
```

**Next step ** is I want to integrate Logstash with Scrapy,

this is part of my Spider codes:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import json
import logging
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import signals
from collections import defaultdict
import time
from ..helper import Helper
from ..items import SampleItem
import requests as py_request
import logging
import logstash
import sys


class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sample'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ['https://www.sample.com/']
    duplicate_found = False
    counter = defaultdict(dict)
    cat = 0
    place_code = 0
    categories = {}
    logstash_logger = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        self.logstash_logger = logging.getLogger('scrapy-logger')
        self.logstash_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.logstash_logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler('localhost', 5000, version=1))
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)

    def get_place_code(self):
        return self.place_code

    def set_place_code(self, value):
        self.place_code = value

    def start_requests(self):
        logging.info(":::>{0} Spider Starting".format(self.name))
        self.logstash_logger.info(":::>{0} Spider Starting".format(self.name))
        self.categories = Helper().get_categories();
        req_timestamp = str(time.time())[:-2]
        for cat in self.categories:
            self.counter[cat['id']] = 0
            logging.info(":::> Start crawling category = {0} ".format(cat['id']))
            self.logstash_logger.info(":::> Start crawling category = {0} ".format(cat['id']))
            start_url = 'https://www.sample.com?c=' + str(
                cat['id'])
            logging.info(start_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=start_url,
                                 method="GET",
                                 callback=self.parse,
                                 meta={'cat': cat['id'], 'requestDateTime': 0, 'counter': 0}
                                 )

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        logging.info(":::>********************************************************************")
        logging.info(":::>{0} Spider Finished.".format(self.name))
        self.logstash_logger.info(":::>{0} Spider Finished.".format(self.name))

        total = 0
        for cat_id, value in self.counter.items():
            logging.info("{0} items imported into {1} category".format(value, cat_id))
            self.logstash_logger.info("{0} items imported into {1} category".format(value, cat_id))
            total += value
        logging.info(":::>******** End Summary; Total : {0} items scraped ***********".format(total))
        self.logstash_logger.info(":::>******** End Summary; Total : {0} items scraped ***********".format(total))

    def parse(self, response):
     # do my parsing stuffs there
     self.logstash_logger.info('End of Data for category')
```

I could see my custom logs in Scrapyd log but nothing has been sent to logstash

```
2018-08-04 13:42:18 [root] INFO: :::> Start crawling category = 43614 
2018-08-04 13:42:18 [scrapy-logger] INFO: :::> Start crawling category = 43614
```

my question is why it's not sending the log to logstash? **How can I log the scrapy logs into the Logstash?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I've done 99% on it, I just needed to get the *scrapy* as the logger

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.logstash_logger = logging.getLogger('scrapy')
    self.logstash_logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler('logstash', 5000, version=1))
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
```

I post the answer maybe it will be useful for another person in the same situation.

Comment: can u post your solution?